# xamarin: I can't add anything to the .Android section

Tags: android, xamarin, icons

In my project I want to add a menu bar. I have downloaded a menu icon now I want to add it under .Android -> Resources. Unfortunately I can't add anything (a prohibition sign appears as a mouse icon). I also tried to add only a png or another file which also does not work.

My project
[image]

The downloaded icons:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can add the files in the appropriate place?

Comment: Your are not able to add an image to drawable ?

Comment: No, I can't add anything to my project. Nor to any other place. For example, I can also add the drawable from another project into this one.

Comment: sorry can you please explain you issue and what r you trying to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is the case, but some times the projects lacks the actual 'Drawable' folder. Create the folder yourself from fileexlorer